# Which VS 2010 version to get?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I want to download VS 2010 Ultimate through my MSDN licence, but I don't see one for the 64-bit.  There's Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 (x86 and x64) - DVD (English), but is that just the server or can I use it for dev too?

Comment: This seems like such a pointless question 12 years later both products are several versions out of date. The naming confusion has gone away, other confusions remain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no 64 bit VS 2010.  If you can, you want to download the [ultimate edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products).  It will give you everything you need to write along with the test tools etc. It will also allow you to access to use the premium edition [code contract generation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/#DevLabs).

[Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx) isn't an IDE.  It's a code/project management tool.

Comment: So what are my options?  I'm on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: The 32 bit version will run on the 64 bit machine without problems.

Comment: @Prabhu: In what way did it "complain"?

Comment: It'll run we use it on all our dev machines and they're all 64-bit.

Comment: @Billy ONeal It said "setup failed", and this is the first line in the error log: [06/16/10,13:22:02] VC 10.0 Runtime (x86): [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for VC 10.0 Runtime (x86), but the file failed verification.

Comment: "file failed verification" == corrupted file. It has nothing to do with the fact that it was installing the x86 Visual C++ runtime. If this is a download, try re-downloading. Otherwise clean your DVD.

Comment: Yeah, I had that problem too.  I had to download it more than once to get it to work.  I  would try the web installer.  That did it for me.

Comment: Thanks guys...I didn't know that VS2010 didn't come in 64bit so I assumed that it was that.

Answer (score 3):

Team Foundation Server is just that -- TFS -- the server side of Microsoft's source control solution. As Kevin said, Visual Studio itself is 32 bit only. There are a whole bunch of reasons why in [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210420002755/https://web.archive.org/web/20160309232651/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx).

Comment: @Glorfindel, TFS is now [Azure Devops Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops/server/) and this Question and Answer have aged to irrelevance.

Comment: @Jodrell yeah, sorry, my script isn't able to detect that and occasionally bumps irrelevant posts. That's one of the reasons it's rate-limited ...